# Using facebook login flow

Tags: facebook, botframework

Have created bot.
Have web site where user has been registered using facebook account.

From facebook manually building login flow :

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?
  client_id={app-id}
  &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
```

In the client_id i am sending my website facebookid. 
What parameter should i use for redirect uri to make redirect to bot ?
Is it possible to get this work this way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the [SimpleFacebookAuthBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleFacebookAuthBot) sample to understand all the pieces.

The RedirectUri must be something in your side that will receive the access code that later will be used to get the access token. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleFacebookAuthBot/Controllers/OAuthCallbackController.cs) is the implementation of that callback in the sample above mentioned.

Comment: you have to clone the full repo (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder)

Comment: In the section controller is more than one controller. OAuthCallbackController. Should i make this one in the bot or in web api solution ? 
Because it inherits from api controller ?

Comment: Ah ok. I realize that i should add http namespace to my solution :) 
using System.Web.Http;

Comment: OAuthCallbackController is the controller that will give the url for the redirect_uri and it will be called by Facebook once the Auth success. Please upvote is this was useful